# Documenting generator functions in JSDoc (for WebStorm completion)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webstorm, jsdoc

First, let me just say I've searched for how to do this, and tried to use [this official resource](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-generator.html) which provided no luck. WebStorm does not recognize my generator function.

Now, let me provide some sample code with my attempt at JSDoc commenting which doesn't seem to work:

```
class Foo {
    /** @param {String} id */
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @generator
     * @yields {{ key: string, value: Number, id: String}}
     */
    *bar() {
        let obj = {a: 1, b:2, c:3};
        for (let l in obj) {
            yield {key: l, value: obj[l], id: this.id};
        }
    }
}

let x = new Foo("newfoo");

const iterator = x.bar();

for (let i of iterator) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

My generator works. If you run this in the console, it outputs exactly what I'd expect it to output.

But inside my `for (let i of iterator)` block, I cannot get `i.` to autocomplete on anything in WebStorm. Does WebStorm not support Generator Function JSDoc or am I just doing it wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `* @returns {Generator<{ key: string, value: Number, id: String}>}` ?

Comment: That does not work, no doc generated for function "range()":
```
/**
 *  Python range()
 *  @generator
 *  @param {number} start
 *  @param {number} end
 *  @returns {Generator<number>}}
 */
function* range(start, end) {
  for (; start < end; ++start) { yield start; }
}
```